# Why can't you pass int[] array into a method that accept object[] array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, boxing

I know that everything in c# inherits from object, so that in my understanding you should always be able to substitute variable of object type to a variable of any other type. Please consider this code, and the questions I put into comments:

```
//Methods declaration
public static void ArrayMethod(object[] a)
{
}
public static void Method(object a)
{
}

//In main method
string[] strArray = { "one", "two" };
int[] intArray = { 1, 3};

ArrayMethod(intArray);   //Here is an error saying "cannot convert from int[] to object[]" (Why is that the case? isn't int of type object?)
ArrayMethod(strArray);  //Here there is no error so apparently converting from string[] to object[] is not an issue (Why is that the case, giving previous error?)

int intVar = 2;    
Method(intVar); //No error here, so apparently converting/boxing from int to object is not an issue as well (Again why is that the case, giving the first error?)
```

Comment: you can change method signature to accept object rather than an array of objects as a parameter public static void ArrayMethod(object a), this should stop errors

Comment: @InBetween ...and that's why exactly? You've only shared your opinion with nothing to support it. My proposed suggestion appears to be working just fine, parameter can be casted back to its type from within the ArrayMethod.

Comment: @J.Tuc where to begin? Because a method expecting an array can now accept anything? Because the signature of a method should *convey* how it should be used and not make the user guess based simply on its name? Because there are much better solutions like using generics that are type safe and eliminate the whole covariance issue? Do you need more? I could go on.